# asp.net programatically created table and css priority

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, hover, css-tables

I have a table which I create programatically in my code behind file and set the colours of alternate row to gray for easier visibility like so:

```
<New cells and rows created here>

tblResults.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
tblResults.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
tblResults.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

if (rowNumber % 2 == 1)
{
    tblRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
}
tblResults.Rows.Add(tblRow);

tblResults.CssClass = "myclass" ;
pnlContent.Controls.Add(tblResults);
```

I also want to have the rows highlighted when a user hovers over them like so:

```
.myclass tr:hover
{
   background: #FCF;
}
```

Now the hover only seems to work for the rows which are not highlighted gray from the c# code which I assumes takes precedence over the css.

How can I also make those gray rows work with the css hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope it helps, I think some where the Style inside the page is overwriting your light Grey Background. Try this it will be ease to find the solution

```
if (rowNumber % 2 == 1)
{
tblRow.Attributes.Add("Class","ClassName_grey");
}
else{
tblRow.Attributes.Add("Class","ClassName_nothing")
}

.myclass tr:hover
{
   background: #FCF;
}
.ClassName_grey {
background: #eeeeee; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
.myclass tr:hover
{
   background-color: #FCF;
}
```

Or adding the !important qualifier.  The former is basically setting the same style as the server-side code should be, whereas your code was setting the less specific background (all aspects of it, not just colour).

Otherwise try viewing the source or using developer tools to see what style attribute you need to overwrite.